# Do SSL Certs containing two wildcards work (esp. on Let's Encrypt)?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain

I want to include two wildcards in an SSL cert (will be) signed by Let's Encrypt: `*.*.thost3.de`. Will this cert match any hostnames matching that rule (e.g. `example.example.thost3.de`, `hello.world.thost3.de`), and can Let's Encrypt accept such wildcards exist in certs they signed?

Answer (score 10):

No this SHOULD NOT (in the RFC meaning of "SHOULD NOT") work, as [documented in RFC 6125](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) (Representation and Verification of Domain-Based Application Service
Identity within Internet Public Key Infrastructure Using X.509 (PKIX)
Certificates in the Context of Transport Layer Security (TLS)):

> If a client matches the reference identifier against a presented
> identifier whose DNS domain name portion contains the wildcard
> character '*', the following rules apply:
>
> 1. The client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier in which the wildcard character comprises a label other than the
>    left-most label (e.g., do not match bar.*.example.net).
> 2. If the wildcard character is the only character of the left-most label in the presented identifier, the client SHOULD NOT compare
>    against anything but the left-most label of the reference identifier
>    (e.g., *.example.com would match foo.example.com but not
>    bar.foo.example.com or example.com).
>
> [...]

Putting these two together:

- you can't have a wildcard elsewhere than the leftmost part (separated by a dot) of the certificate: an inner wildcard is invalid.
- you can't have a wildcard certificate match additional label part (ie: separated by a dot) on its left: again that means that if a valid single wildcard were used, nothing with an additional left part can match (so hello.world.thost3.de can't match the certificate *.thost3.de).

What you can do is issue a certificate with a lot of SAN parts possibly themselves with a (valid) wildcard. <s>But I'm not sure at all that you can get this accepted by Let's Encrypt.</s>

EDIT: `*.stackexchange.com` is signed by Let's Encrypt with multiple SANs having a wildcard.

Example:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect stackexchange.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null| openssl x509 -noout -text | grep -A1 'X509v3 Subject Alternative Name' | tr ',' '\n'
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.askubuntu.com
 DNS:*.blogoverflow.com
 DNS:*.mathoverflow.net
 DNS:*.meta.stackexchange.com
 DNS:*.meta.stackoverflow.com
 DNS:*.serverfault.com
 DNS:*.sstatic.net
 DNS:*.stackexchange.com
 DNS:*.stackoverflow.com
 DNS:*.stackoverflow.email
 DNS:*.superuser.com
 DNS:askubuntu.com
 [...]
```

Comment: "is issue a certificate with a lot of SAN parts", yes, you could issue that (in a self-signed cert for example), but no browser (at least as far as I know) accepts that. So these are utterly useless :)

Comment: No, what I meant was: dual (or more) wildcard certificates, so *.*.serverfault.com would not be accepted by browsers, even if you managed to sign such a certificate.

Comment: @TobiasMädel ah yes I agree with this.

Comment: Is there documented rationale for why this is a “should not” as opposed to a “must not”?

Comment: And why this is a "should not" as opposed to a "must"?

Comment: The point is whether an RA (Registration Authority) would actually accept such CSR (Certificate Signing Requests) when the subject is not allowed. It's a rather useless discussion what such a certificate would do unless you actually get one. See the definition of **Wildcard Domain Name** in https://letsencrypt.org/documents/isrg-cp-v3.3/